# Dissmiss current View Controller back to MainView Controller after a Time Interval IOS 7

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uiviewcontroller

Hi in my app I'm uploading images from my device to sever in that everything works fine but now I'm getting some issues with that. After uploading it has to go back to main view controller automatically after uploading the image. Its not working please tell me how to do that.

Upload coding.

```
    NSString *urlString = @"url";

    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[[NSMutableURLRequest alloc]init]autorelease];
    [request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]] ;
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

    NSString *boundary = @"---------------------------14737809831466499882746641449";
    NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@",boundary];
    [request addValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];

    NSMutableData *body = [NSMutableData data];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n",boundary]dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"userfile\"; filename=\".jpg\"\r\n"dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[@"Content-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n\r\n"dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[NSData dataWithData:imageData]];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@--\r\n", boundary]dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [request setHTTPBody:body];

    NSData *returnData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:nil];
    NSString *returnString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:returnData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    NSLog(@"%@data",returnString);


    **[self performSelector:@selector(dissMissViewController) withObject:self afterDelay:2.0f];**
```

Dismiss coding.

```
     - (void)dissMissViewController
  {
   [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
   [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
  }
```

After uploading i want to go back to my main view controller please tell this is right way to do it. Is any alternative way to make it done.

Thanks.

Comment: try `popToRootViewController` method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First thing is that you have to know that image upload success or not and at the success you need to dismiss and pop back to main viewcontroller like this :-

```
-(void)dissMissViewController
  {
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{
    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];}];
  }
```

**you can also pop a particular view controller like:-**

```
for (UIViewController *controller in [self.navigationController viewControllers])
{
    if ([controller isKindOfClass:[yourviewcontroller class]])
    {
        [self.navigationController popToViewController:controller animated:YES];
        break;
    }
}
```

**you can also use this bellow line of code to pop a rootviewcontroller:-**

```
[self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES]
```

**NOTE: use this pop code in to completion block of DismissViewcontroller**

Comment: pls tell how to go back to my main view controller

Comment: @Nintin i used this [self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES] in my dismissview controller its not working i dont know y

Comment: @Nitin are you using storyboard?

Answer (score 0):

1st You should use Asynchronous method for that,  because currently you are doing in main thread.

Send Data to server using Connection's delegate methods,
and Use Connection's delegate method `connectionDidFinishLoading` for get notify that you have uploaded image successfully.

or Try this

```
- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection{

[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{
    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];}];

}
```